# Python curve_fit not fitting correct sin

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I used the normal Scipy curve_fit code with my own values from a csv document.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv

x = [];
y = [];
with open('test2.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        v = f"{row[0]}";
        u = f"{row[1]}";
        x.append(int(u));
        y.append(float(v));
        line_count += 1;
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
  
def test(x, a, b): 
    return a * np.sin(b * x) 
param, param_cov = curve_fit(test, x, y) 
  
  
print("Sine funcion coefficients:") 
print(param) 
print("Covariance of coefficients:") 
print(param_cov)
```

The values are measured with an Arduino and an acceleration sensor. In Excel they draw a beautiful Sine.
The test2.csv file:

```
1.03;3024
1.28;3027
2.16;3039
3.58;3050
4.04;3053
4.96;3064
5.04;3067
5.03;3072
4.23;3090
4.02;3093
3.88;3097
2.78;3123
2.11;3144
2.02;3147
0.99;3170
0.02;3184
-0.18;3187
-0.91;3198
-1.15;3203
-1.97;3217
-2.12;3220
-3.62;3264
-4.53;3308
-4.56;3312
-4.67;3322
-4.75;3326
-4.97;3338
-5;3341
-5.02;3345
-4.95;3348
-4.65;3362
-4.6;3366
-4.49;3371
-3.96;3385
-3.29;3406
-1.97;3439
-1.6;3450
-0.28;3476
```

And the output of the Python script:

```
Processed 38 lines.
Sine funcion coefficients:
[0.96405843 1.00058573]
Covariance of coefficients:
[[ 7.20387348e-01 -2.68335160e-05]
 [-2.68335160e-05  6.82099708e-08]]
```

As you can see, the coefficients are not the sine from the file.
What is the problem with the reading or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have all the independent variables defined for a sin() function. An arbitrary sin() function is of the form A*sin(B*x + C), where C is the phase. I don't think you'll get a fit using any method without all the independent variables defined.
2. Do you know that the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm (used by scipy.optimize.curve_fit) works for periodic functions? I am not familiar with it, but curve fitters in general usually don't do well with periodic functions - that's why Fourier transforms are used in those cases (and I suggest you investigate).